# ResetBindings for just one column on a datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I am working with windows forms using C#.

I currently have an object bound to a DataGridView.

One of the properties of the object is `Currentprice`

This is updated every few seconds from an API.

In order for this change to be reflected in the DataGridView, I am calling

```
MyObject.ResetBindings();
```

every time its updated.

This works Fine, but there is a noticeable flicker every time this happens.
Is there any way to refresh only the `CurrentPrice` column in the datagridview?

Comment: In the end I never worked out how to do it, but I did get rid of the problem by calling resetbindings every second instead of every time the property is updated (since there were many objects bound to the grid it was previously being rebounf many times a second).

Comment: It also helped to run resetBindings asynchronously.